# How to format correctly my data to show them as a table

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a group of classes on monday and they take place in 5 different rooms. I'd like to present them in columns based on location using divs and sort by location, start. I get the data no problem (find all classes that run on monday) but it simply lists it in one column so my foreach arrays are incorrect.
here's $data

```
$calendar = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $calendar[$row[0]][] = $row;
}
foreach($calendar as $key => $row) {
       foreach($row as $field => $value) { 
           $recNew[$field][] = $value;
       }
}
```

here's array exerpt

```
    array(1) {
     [""]=> array(20) 
     {
     [0]=> array(1) {
     ["calendars"]=> array(9) {
     ["id"]=> string(3) "742" 
     ["title"]=> string(4) "Yoga" 
     ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
     ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
     ["start_time"]=> string(8) "20:00:00" 
     ["end_time"]=> string(8) "21:00:00" 
     ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 1" 
     ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
     ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1" 
      } 
     }
     [1]=> array(1) { 
     ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
     ["id"]=> string(3) "743" 
     ["title"]=> string(2) "GX" 
     ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
     ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
     ["start_time"]=> string(8) "18:00:00" 
     ["end_time"]=> string(8) "18:45:00" 
     ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 1" 
     ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
     ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } } 
    [2]=> array(1) { 
    ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "447" 
    ["title"]=> string(4) "Spin"  
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "09:15:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "10:00:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 1" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1" 
     } } 

    [3]=> array(1) { 
    ["calendars"]=> array(22) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "448" 
    ["title"]=> string(4) "Spin" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "12:15:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "13:00:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 1" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"  } } 

    [4]=> array(1) { 
    ["calendars"]=> array(22) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "684" 
    ["title"]=> string(4) "Spin" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "16:30:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "17:15:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 1" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } } 

    [5]=> array(1) { 
    ["calendars"]=> array(22) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "545" 
    ["title"]=> string(4) "Yoga" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "18:15:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "19:00:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 1" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"
    } } 

[6]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "549" 
    ["title"]=> string(4) "Yoga" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "09:00:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "10:00:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 2" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"  } } 

    [7]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "688" 
    ["title"]=> string(7) "Weights"
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "10:10:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "11:00:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 2" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"
    } } 

    [8]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "572" 
    ["title"]=> string(4) "Yoga" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "12:10:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "13:10:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 2" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"  
    } } 

    [9]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "548" 
    ["title"]=> string(4) "Spin" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "16:00:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "16:55:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 2" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } } 

    [10]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "573" 
    ["title"]=> string(11) "Power Yoga"
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "18:45:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "19:45:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 2" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } } 

    [11]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "742" 
    ["title"]=> string(4) "Yoga" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "20:00:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "21:00:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 2" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"
    } } 

    [12]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "552" 
    ["title"]=> string(5) "Zumba" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "10:15:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "11:15:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 3" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"
    } } 

    [13]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "622" 
    ["title"]=> string(4) "Yoga"
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "11:30:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "12:00:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 3" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"
    } } 

    [14]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "570" 
    ["title"]=> string(22) "Body Pump (Doriana P.)" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "12:15:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "13:15:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 3" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } } 

    [15]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "740" 
    ["title"]=> string(4) "Spin" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "13:30:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "14:00:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 4" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1
    } } 

    [16]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "623" 
    ["title"]=> string(7) "Weights" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "16:45:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "17:45:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 4" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"
    } } 

    [17]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "586" 
    ["title"]=> string(2) "GX" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "18:00:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "18:30:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 5" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"
    } } 

    [18]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "613" 
    ["title"]=> string(7) "Weights"
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "18:45:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "19:30:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 5" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"
    } } 

    [19]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(9) { 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "621" 
    ["title"]=> string(5) "Zumba" 
    ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2015-09-14" 
    ["end_date"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    ["start_time"]=> string(8) "19:45:00" 
    ["end_time"]=> string(8) "20:45:00" 
    ["location"]=> string(8) "Studio 5" 
    ["calendar_category_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["recur_mon"]=> string(1) "1"
} } 
    }
```

[image: table of classes in studios]

```
    <?php foreach ($recNew as $key => $classes) { ?>
    <div class="locations-wrapper">
        <div class="my-locations"><?php echo $location[$key]; ?></div>
        <?php foreach ($classes as $class) : ?>
        <!-- class info here -->
        <div class="class">
            <h4><?php echo $class['calendars']['title']; ?></h4>
        </div><!-- end div class -->
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

This is what I get
[image: table of classes]

Might need the locations to be the key for this to work.

Comment: I don't see exactly how your script generates the output you need, but if it does, floating the locations with their content left in css would solve your problem. In general, if you can get the right html structure with your php, the styling can be pretty much anything you want with css.

Comment: consider rotating the table so that `Studio 1, Studio 2,...` are stacked on top of each other with their classes going out to the right. it'll be easier to code and style

Comment: You could add another layer to the array for the location. would go `"" => array( 0 => array(  'calendars' => array(   'Studio 2' => array     "id"=> "742",...` easier to for-loop through

Comment: Yeah I have a left float on div with set width but my problems are in the script and getting the different locations to start in a new column.

Comment: @sloga: add your $data array in your code for I can help you

Comment: @developer added more data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using html table for printing result:

```
<?php 
$calendar = array();
foreach ($data as $row) 
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++)
    {   if(!array_key_exists($row[$i]["calendars"]["location"], $calendar))     
            $calendar[$row[$i]["calendars"]["location"]] = array();
        array_push($calendar[$row[$i]["calendars"]["location"]], $row[$i]["calendars"]);
    }
}
?>
<table>
<tr>
<?php
foreach($calendar as $key => $row):
?>
<td>

<table>
<tr><td><?php echo $key;?></td></tr>
<?php 
foreach($row as $r):
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $r["title"]; ?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
</td>
<?php endforeach;?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sweet! I was able to use this and design with divs and css. Thanks!
<div class="overflow">
<?php
foreach($calendar as $key => $row):
?>
<div class="days-wrapper">
  <div class="days-of-week">
  <?php echo $key; ?>
  </div>
  
<?php 
foreach($row as $r):
?>
<!-- class info here -->
<div class="class">
<h4> <?php echo $r["title"]; ?></h4>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
</div>

<?php endforeach;?>
</div><!-- end div overflow -->
</div><!-- end div classes -->

Comment: @developer,  I don't understand this question,  but if you do, please edit it to give it a more indicative title.

Comment: @mickmackusa, done, title is updated

Comment: I am afraid the title is still too vague/ambiguous to be helpful.  Please try to give it unique context.  "Formatting data" can mean a thousand different things.  Probably better to try to describe how the data is grouped atypically in the HTML table.